# Bootstrap 3 - fixed width + fluid columns, re-ordering columns, columns gutters

Tags: html, responsive

I have read some post here regarding the followings:

1. Gutter between columns
2. No gutter on the "Most left" and "Most Right" columns
3. 2 Fixed size columns
4. Re-order columns based on screen sizes

I have a layout that require the combination of all. Attached is the [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3sAN.png) mock. And here is what I have done so far [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4L2ry734/22/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 a">News</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 b">Videos</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 c">MRec1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 d">MRec2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 e">Button1</div>
  </div>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).resize(function() {
    iTargetWidth = $(window).width();
    if (iTargetWidth <= 768) {
      $(".b").insertAfter(".e");
      $(".c").insertBefore(".a");
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Columns i.e. elements with `class="col-*-*"` have 15px of padding on the left and right.
2. The element with the `container` class has 15px of padding on the left and right. The `row` class has a margin of -15px on the left and right. This removes the effect of the `container`'s padding.
3. All `col-*-*` classes are relative.

4.To do this you would use classes like `pull-md-left` or `pull-sm-right`

For a better understanding refer to the documentation on http://getbootstrap.com/components/